# Use checkboxes to restrict search to belonging objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on a rails 3.2 app that basically acts as a blog with tags.

Tags are related to posts in a has_many :through association. (post have many tags through taggigns)
Don't know why the app doesn't have a habtm association since it would have worked the same, but that's what I have.

The app can now show the list of posts belonging to a tag like this:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])    
    @posts = @tag.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10) 
  end
  ...
end
```

This way the page example.com/tags/1 will show all the posts with a tag matching ID 1.

What I have to do is modify this app to have checkboxes for tags and to restrict the search for example to posts having both tag 1 and 4.

Can someone please give me an input on where to start or maybe some resources to look for? I think I should use a join but I'm not sure this is the case.

Thank you.

========

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. Anyway, as suggested by ok32, user1083138's solutions was creating duplicates. At the same time ok32's one was resulting in empty arrays (probably it's due to my poor implementation of the tagging system).

I went up with this solution that works just fine:

```
  def self.tag_query(list)
    Post.joins(:tags).where(:tags => { :name => list } ).having("count(tags.name) = ?", list.count ).group('posts.id')
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, JOIN is your friend:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(:tags => { :id => [tag_ids] } )
```

Check this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) as reference.

Also you have to create\modify views and controllers to show check-boxes and populate "tag_ids" variable.

Comment: I actually find this solution to be cleaner and easier to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is your friend, but.. To avoid duplicate results I'd suggest using something like that:

In the controller:

```
@tags = Tag.find(params[:tag_ids])
@posts = Post.tagged_with(@tags)
```

In the `Post` model:

```
def self.tagged_with(tags)
  post_ids = select('posts.id').joins(:tags).where('tags.id in (?)', tags)
  where(id: post_ids)
end
```

**update:**

I have modified the model method a bit:

```
def self.tagged_with(tags)
  post_ids = joins(:taggings).where('taggings.tag_id in (?)', tags)
  where(id: post_ids)
end
```

What has changed:

1. I removed unnecessary `select('posts.id')`. It works well without it.
2. Now it generates more efficient query (it joins with one table instead of two).

Comment: Cool, this will probably work fine. Of course this will not be anymore fit for the tags#show action. What is the most "railsish" place to put it?

Comment: I edited the original post with a solution. Thank you for your help